# why does ngRepeat not work with value in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following code

http://jsfiddle.net/wnWY6/682/

The HTML

```
<div ng-app>
    <div ng-controller="TestCtrl" ng-repeat="icecream in iceCreams track by $index">
        <div ng-repeat="a in range(icecream.rating)"> star icon</div>
        <div ng-repeat="a in range(icecream.rating)"> star icon</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
function TestCtrl($scope) {
        $scope.iceCreams = [
        {
        name: "toto",
        rating: "3",
      },
      {
        name: "fofo",
        rating: "4",
      },
    ];
    $scope.range = function(n) {
        return new Array(parseInt(n));
    };
};
```

But it doesn't display anything, I'm not sure that I'm doing wrong. Any help will really be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `ng-controller`, you need to register your controller to the module. But before that, you need to instantiate the module with `ng-app="app"`.

Then it's enough to add for a working example:

```
angular.module('app', []).controller('TestCtrl', TestCtrl);
```

Beyond this issue, you need to separate `ng-controller` and `ng-repeat`, or you will have multiple instances of the same controller. Additionally you need `track by $index` for inner `ng-repeat` that you use.

---

Full code:

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('TestCtrl', TestCtrl);

function TestCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.iceCreams = [{
      name: "toto",
      rating: "3",
    },
    {
      name: "fofo",
      rating: "4",
    },
  ];
  $scope.range = function(n) {
    return new Array(parseInt(n));
  };
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="TestCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="icecream in iceCreams track by $index">
    <div ng-repeat="a in range(icecream.rating) track by $index"> star icon</div>
    <div ng-repeat="a in range(icecream.rating) track by $index"> star icon</div>
  </div>
</div>
```